# How to exclude a particular category from the category list

Tags: categories

I'm trying to edit a wordpress theme.

The following is the section of code where the list of categories is retrieved and displayed in a drop-down menu.

```
<p>
<label for="entrycat">* <?php _e( "Question category:", "sofa_qanda" ); ?></label>
<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Select&show_count=0&orderby=name&echo=0&hide_empty=0' );
$select = preg_replace( '|<select(.*?).*?>|i', '<select id="entrycat" name="entrycat" tabindex="4">', $select );
echo $select;
?>
</p>
```

I what to exclude a particular category, say category id 10 from the list. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

use the 'exclude' parameter; 
example:

```
$select = wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Select&show_count=0&orderby=name&echo=0&hide_empty=0&exclude=10' );
```